# How can a compiler lint pass gain access to conditional-compilation attributes like #[cfg(..)]?

Tags: rust, lint

Rust has a very good lint interface, divided into `EarlyLintPass` and `LateLintPass` trait objects. Unfortunately, even the early passes don't see `#[cfg]` or `#[cfg_attr]` attributes, and thus cannot lint them. Is there a way to reliably get them while also following lint levels?